# redirect everything with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for quite some time here to find something similar, but I am unable to find what I am looking for.

I would like to redirect an old Project discarded Project to a new one, they are only partly similar and I would like to redirect the matches, and afterwards everything else, while removing every

I think I remembere that htaccess Rules are worked one after another, so I can simply add 301's above the redirect everything else, but it turns out that this code

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /match1.html https://www.domain.tld/match1/
Redirect 301 /match2.html https://www.domain.tld/match2/
Redirect 301 /match3.php&page=6 https://www.domain.tld/match3/?

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .*? https://www.domain.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

redirects simply everything directly to https://www.domain.tld/

The Old Project mas completely manual work with 450+ static html pages and another ~100 php files, so I hope there is a more simple way that creating a huge .htaccess to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide the present and the destination URL, it will help to understand your problem better

Comment: To be honest, I would probably just redirect the user with some GET param which would trigger some pop-up that the page has changed it's domain, setttings, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule redirecting everything to `https://www.domain.tld/` because of your last rule, and for redirecting enbloc you can use regular expression for match try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If there are other certain patterns please provide them and I am assuming you are using the rules in root `.htaccess` or respective directory.

Comment: Yes, I am using the rules from root and only if not otherwise possible I would create folders to have them redirected from there. -- I will try to implement the Code as soon as possible, but as of now I am at home where I have very limited access to my sites and code. So a tryout isn't possible before monday, what will be the earliest time to mark question as solved/reward the bounty. Kind Regards

Comment: There is no hurry take your time and let me know! and one more thing do you want to redirect every url to new site or only certain urls.

Comment: First certain specific ones to specific new targets and afterwards the rest to the main page

Comment: Well, sadly I am unable to reconstruct your code :( BUT, I have found another solution with ONE flaw i think. `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect specific pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(match1\.html)$ https://www.domain.tld/match1/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(match2\.html)$ https://www.domain.tld/match2/ [R=301,L,NC]

# Redirect all others to the new domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/ [R=301,L]` --- if there is a query like ?p=123 it won't work and sends to root. Any idea why?

Comment: old comment deleted.. made it myself harder than it needs to be. If you upload stuff into the wrong folder its no wonder that nothing works. Only remaining Problem are the URL's with &p=123 Query's that always get redirected to http://www.domain.tld/ instead of the desired target. But after all, the most important part is solved now

Comment: What is your target for query string?

Comment: If you still haven't solved, maybe this link http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/ can help to give you some "light"